# Use return data from dynamic highcharts chart in Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm implementing a graph in Shiny where users can create their own time series with the "draggable point" option from the http://jkunst.com/highcharter/oldindex.html#draggable-points example. I would like to use the "new" datapoints in server.r and also show them in a table. If someone could help me how to return the data points, that would be great.Please find the code below.

Thanks, TIm

server.r:

```
data(citytemp, package = "highcharter")
   function(input, output) {
 hcbase <- reactive({
   # hcbase <- function() highchart() 
   hc <- highchart() 


   if (input$credits)
     hc <- hc %>% hc_credits(enabled = TRUE, text = "Highcharter", href =    "http://jkunst.com/highcharter/")

if (input$exporting)
  hc <- hc %>% hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)

if (input$theme != FALSE) {
  theme <- switch(input$theme,
                  null = hc_theme_null(),
                  economist = hc_theme_economist(),
                  dotabuff = hc_theme_db(),
                  darkunica = hc_theme_darkunica(),
                  gridlight = hc_theme_gridlight(),
                  sandsignika = hc_theme_sandsignika(),
                  fivethirtyeight = hc_theme_538(),
                  chalk = hc_theme_chalk(),
                  handdrwran = hc_theme_handdrawn()
    )

    hc <- hc %>% hc_add_theme(theme)
  }

  hc

})


 output$table <-renderDataTable({
   #Output from graph
   data.table(month=citytemp$month,berlin=citytemp$berlin
              ,berlin_dragged=citytemp$berlin)#Here I want to use the dragged data. something linke input$highchart$... should do the trick I guess...
 })

output$highchart <- renderHighchart({

data(citytemp)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(animation = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "draggable points demo") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = month.abb) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(

    stickyTracking = FALSE
        ),
    column = list(
      stacking = "normal"
    ),
    line = list(
      cursor = "ns-resize"
    )
    ) %>% 

  hc_add_series(
    data = citytemp$berlin,
    draggableY = TRUE
  )

})



 }
```

ui.r

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("highcharter")
library("dplyr")
library("viridisLite")
library("markdown")
library("quantmod")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("treemap")
library("forecast")
library("DT")
rm(list = ls())

dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(title = "highcharter", disable = FALSE),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Examples", tabName = "examples", icon = icon("bar-chart"))
    )
    #,
    #div(includeMarkdown("hcterinfo.md"), style = "padding:10px")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    # tags$head(tags$script(src = "js/ga.js")),
    # tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/custom_fixs.css")),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "examples",
              fluidRow(

              box(width = 6, highchartOutput("highchart")),
              box(width = 6, dataTableOutput("table"))

      )
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: I'm just answer this in the repository https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/42

Comment: Please http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key parts are:

- In highcharts use the drop event (JS code).
- In the previous code event use the Shiny.onInputChange('inputname', data). This tell shiny that manualforecast data has change so you can use in a render function.
- Then create a renderObject (renderTable) calling input$inputname. So you can get the updated data and do whatever you want.

Key lines of code

```
    hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      point = list(
        events = list(
          drop = JS("function(){
                    console.log(this.series)
                    window.data = _.map(this.series.data, function(e) { return e.y })
                    Shiny.onInputChange('inputname', data);
                    }"))
          )))
```

And then:

```
renderDataTable({
   ...
   var <- input$inputname # listening the drop event 
   ...
```

Reference: https://github.com/jbkunst/shiny-apps/blob/master/highcharter/server.R#L158

Comment: I really like the library, however the rendering is somewhat slow for large datasets (>100k points) so I stick with `dygraphs`. Will there be additional functionality implemented to support large datasets?

Comment: @PorkChop Right hc dont work so well. Highcharts team are working on [boost](http://www.highcharts.com/articles/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost) module. I tried to [implement](http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/highcharter-boost) this module but breaks other functionalities (maybe I'll implement this htmwidget/module separately). `dygraphs` is a nice chart library too, sadly is ts oriented only.

Comment: Yeah Boost is nice, I recall someone suggesting this to `Rcharts` too, Ramnath said he will look into it. Anyway, great job with the library!